# shell script inconsistent with java Runtime

Tags: java, linux, shell, batch-file, runtime

Following is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -s $CATALINA_HOME ]; then
echo "Error: CATALINA_HOME not set!!!"
exit -1
fi

SHUTDOWN_SCRIPT="$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh"
STARTUP_SCRIPT="$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh"

#execute shutdown.sh
echo "Doing Shutdown"
$SHUTDOWN_SCRIPT
sleep 5
#execute startup.sh
echo "Doing Startup"
$STARTUP_SCRIPT

exit 0
```

it is just shutting down and startup is not working.

and i'm running with following code

```
Runtime rn = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc; 
proc = rn.exec("/script/restart.sh");
proc.waitFor();
```

i had a similar issue with .bat file and i fixed it with

```
Runtime rn = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc; 
proc = rn.exec("cmd /c start /script/restart.bat"); 
proc.waitFor();
```

calling with "cmd /c start" solved my issue any similar suggestion for .sh file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check file privileges whether it has execute permission, if not set execute permission.

Execute `which bash` it'll return a path of `bash` try with example `/bin/bash yourShell.sh` or `/bin/sh yourShell.sh` in `Runtime#exec` or `ProcessBuilder` (recommended)

`saravana@ubuntu:~$which bash
/bin/bash`

```
    String[] commmands = { "/bin/bash", "/script/restart.sh" }; // or { "/bin/sh", "/script/restart.sh" }
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commmands); //or
    new ProcessBuilder(commmands).start(); //Recommended
```